# ¿Como instalo las extensiones de python para usar OpenCV y Deep Learning?

Tags: python, opencv

Hola Buenos días tengo un problema quiero probar un programa que permite colorear imagenes blanco y negro a color pero no me deja mi visual-studio correrlo como corresponde  a través de este enlace  https://www.datasmarts.net/como-colorear-imagenes-en-blanco-y-negro-usando-deep-learning-y-opencv/ pero me apareció un error de instalación ya nose cómo instalarlo me podrían ayudar a solucionarlo.

> pip install -r requirements.txt
> Collecting numpy==1.19.2
> Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done
> Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
> Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [200 lines of output]
Running from numpy source directory.
setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()

Answer (score 0):

El error que mencionas puede deberse a varios problemas. Una posible causa es que estés intentando instalar una versión de numpy que no es compatible con tu versión de Python. Por lo general, se recomienda utilizar la última versión de numpy, que puedes instalar con el siguiente comando:

```
pip install numpy
```

Si aún sigues teniendo problemas, es posible que necesites asegurarte de que tienes instaladas todas las dependencias necesarias para compilar y ejecutar el programa. Esto puede incluir herramientas como GCC, Cython y otros paquetes de desarrollo. Si no estás seguro de cómo instalar estas dependencias, te recomendaría consultar la documentación de numpy.

Otra posible causa del error que mencionas puede ser que estés intentando instalar una versión de numpy que ya está instalada en tu sistema. En ese caso, puedes intentar desinstalar la versión existente y luego volver a instalarla con el comando que mencioné anteriormente.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema que tienes. Si necesitas más ayuda, no dudes en preguntar.